# ¿Cómo compilar mi programa y que incluya las librerías externas que utiliza?

Tags: c#, imagen, pdf, itextsharp

Igual es una tontería, pero no sé como hacer para que mi programa incluya en el archivo EXE todas las librerías que necesita...

A ver, utilizo el Microsoft visual studio, mi programa está hecho en C#, compilo con las opciones "release" y "any CPU", le doy a "inicio" (el triangulo verde de Play) y el programa va de maravilla al ejecutarse desde el Visual Studio, sin embargo si voy a buscar el archivo EXE y lo ejecuto directamente me da error.
Me dice:
[image: Error]

Mi programa utiliza la librería externa iTextsharp, e interpreto que el problema está en que no se ha añadido en el compilado.

Entonces, ¿cómo puedo linkar en mi programa todas las librerías que necesita, para que se ejecute directamente desde su archivo EXE en cualquier ordenador que tenga el programa?

Comment: cuando le das compilar, en tu proyecto, tienes una carpeta Bin, dentro de ella tiene una carpeta llamada "debug" y otra "release", en esa carpeta, debe estar tu .exe y todas las .dll del proyecto, no las vez en esa carpeta?

Comment: Depende de qué versión de .NET estés usando. Si estás usando .NET 4 o más reciente hay opciones para generar un ejecutable **autocontenido**. Sino creo que no es posible.

Comment: MrDonPh0x:

Efectivamente en esa carpeta veo mi EXE y la DLL, además de más archivos. Si la DLL acompaña mi archivo todo funciona, pero lo que pregunto es ¿si puedo linkar la DLL dentro del EXE, para que todo vaya en un único archivo?

Comment: Porque mejor no haces un instalador? es lo que se suele hacer.. porque ademas, si quien lo va a instalar no tiene todos los paquetes .net necesarios, no le va  a funcionar...

Comment: que tipo de aplicación es, un WPF, Consola o Windows Form?
como dice gbianchi, lo ideal es hacer un instalador, Visual Studio cuenta con ClickOnce

Comment: @AdolfoHernández hay una aplicacion que se llama ILMerge buscala, esta te permite incrustar dlls en tu ejecutable, tambien puedes investigar sobre la libreria Costura.Fody